# want to show month name and leap year in python

Tags: python

The program should prompt the user to enter the month and year (as integers) and display the number of days in the month, showing the month name. For example, if the user entered month 2 and the year 2000, the program should display:

```
Enter a month as an integer (1-12): 2
Enter a year: 2000
There are 29 days in February of 2000
```

```
def numberOfDays(month, year):
    daysInMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if month > len(daysInMonths) or year < 0 or month < 0:
        return "Please enter a valid month/year"

    return daysInMonths[month-1] + int((year % 4) == 0 and month == 2)

def main():
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    print(month, year, "has", numberOfDays(month, year) , "days")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

In this program, I want to show the month's name and print it in the last.
How would the program be then? What should I do?
For example, if the input is 1, then 1 should be assigned as January and also be printed.

Comment: Just a note on finding New Year. it is `year % 400 == 0 or year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0`

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
dict_month = {1:"January", 2: "February"} # and so on ...

print(dict_month.get(month), year, "has", numberOfDays(month, year) , "days")
```

Comment: @farhan, glad I could help! Could you mark this answer as selected answer than? Helps future readers with the same question as you to find the answer faster and gives me a few points. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the calendar module to get this done:

```
import calendar
months = list(calendar.month_name) #gets the list of months by name
obj = calendar.Calendar()

y, m = int(input('Enter year: ')), int(input('Enter a month as an integer (1-12): '))
days = calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1]

print(f'There are {days} days in {months[m]} of {y}')
```

And if all you want to do is to check if year is leap:

```
import calendar
print(calendar.isleap(int(input('Enter year: '))))
```